# Passing parameter from controller to controller while including some XHTML into another XHTML in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

These are lines from parent.XHTML which is including other (child.xhtml):

parent.xhtml

```
                <ui:include src="/view/user/includes/child.xhtml">

                    <ui:param name="passingId" value="#{parentController.myobj.id}"></ui:param>
                </ui:include>
            </ui:fragment>
```

There is also a `childController`.
I initialize `myobj` in `parentController`'s `@PostConstruct` method.
I want to childController be aware of `passingId`.

i tried to write `#{childController.setPassingId(parentController.myobj.id)}`

but it didnt work?

is there a way?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried in your `hild.xhtml` the following

`#{childController.setPassingId(passingId)}`

?

Comment: it worked but i must use it in `@PostConstruct` of childController. or somewhere like it. but `@PostConstruct` runs before `#{childController.setPassingId(passingId)}` runs in xhtml.

Comment: how about using the parentController as a managed property in your childController @PostConstruct ?